# switching from sonar-runner 2.3 to 2.4 results in error on analysis

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I have a multi module project set up for sonar analysis using way #2 from [Analyzing with SonarQube Runner](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Runner#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeRunner-Multi-moduleProject).

The only difference is that I dont use a global sonar-project.properties file.
The global properties are defined in jenkins in the sonar runner build step.

This works perfectly fine with Sonar Runner 2.3.
As soon as I switch from 2.3 to Sonar Runner 2.4 this fails with the error that the mandatory sonar.sources property is not defined.

I have tried setting it in my global properties to sonar.sources=src but then sonar can't analyze a module that doesn't use src as source folder.

It looks to me like Sonar Runner 2.4 doesn't use the module's sonar-project properties anymore.

Or is there a way to tell Sonar Runner 2.4 to use the module's sonar-project.properties file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two supported layout when using SQ Runner are:

- put all properties of all modules in root `sonar-project.properties` file
- put each module properties in its own `sonar-project.properties` *in addition to the root `sonar-project.properties`*

It is also possible to add properties via command line (this is what you do when you define properties in SQ Runner build step).

Your attempt to not have a root `sonar-project.properties` but having individual `sonar-project.properties` files in sub modules was not identified as a supported use case. So I'm not very surprised it is no more supported (it was likely a side effect).

See http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Runner#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeRunner-Multi-moduleProject